# Best Way to Develop a text code editor with syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I am developing a code editor with syntax highlighting and detecting; I am following current architecture for it;
a) Have a text area with z index at 10
b) Have div's above text area with z index 40 which mask contents typed with custom colors needed for syntax highlighting

Can some one suggest me better architectural approaches for building a custom code editor with syntax highlighting and detecting

Comment: It is always better to either create something like jsFiddle or simple paste related script/code for easier review...

Comment: How can i add dynamic spans to content typed in text-area instantly, i need to color code as per my requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out [AceEditor](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about)?
Not sure exactly why you would want to start working on a new editor, which will probably take a lot of time to develop and not use what's already out there, functional, fully tested and with a big and vibrant community around it.

Comment: we have a custom proprietary programming language with its own syntax and methods, so i need a text editor for users to identify key words and syntax

Comment: Ace editor is extensible, so rather than build a new editor, you could extend AceEditor by creating a new mode (syntax file). I think this will be faster. Here is the link to their wiki on extending the editor [Ace wiki](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode).